# Check formula fields in apex

Tags: apex

I know we can use describe calls to identify if a field is a custom field or not. Similarly, is there any way we can check if a particular field is a formula field in apex? As per my knowledge and experience, i have never seen a method that can tell us that.. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DescribeFieldResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) class has a method [getCalculatedFormula()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getCalculatedFormula). If this method returns a non null value for a given field then that field is a formula field.

**Update**(based on the comments below): We can also use the [isCalculated()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isCalculated) method which returns true if the field is a custom formula field, false otherwise.

Comment: So it returns the formula or the calculated value?

Comment: it would return formula (dont know why would they name the method like that!), the calculated value is anyway available on the field :)

Comment: Rajiv - Yes I checked and it returns the complete formula. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Instead of  getCalculatedFormula(), you can also use isCalculated() method. This method returns true/false instead of complete formula.

Comment: nice! i am sorry i completely overlooked that as I have been reading the actual formulas. Thanks for sharing though! :)

Comment: No problem .. !!